# Where can I find the latest version of Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll?

Tags: ecl

I want to use External Content Library provided in Tridion 2013. Where can I find the latest version of Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll to add as a reference in my provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install the ECL as part of CM Installation/Repair

[image]

after repair/installation check following location or mentioned by Saurabh  on your CM box,

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\tridion.externalContentLibrary
```

Answer (score 2):

All the client DLLs could be found under the folder " **%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\client** " on the CM box.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I tried to find it at the above mentioned location but could not find it.